# Making noises you get from playing guitar

Tags: sound-design, noise, guitar

When someone plays the guitar, his fingers go over the snares creating the guitar sound we all love. But it also creates noises (try sliding your hand over the snares in the direction that they go).

I want to record them and put them under my synthesized guitar track but I don't have a guitar.

Is there a way I can recreate these guitar noises?

I prefer to use serum or massive for my sound design but a generic "how-to" will work fine.

Comment: Any links to an example of that sound?

Comment: As I said I would be happy to record it but I can't. I wrote this on my phone so I will check tomorrow if I can find some good material. Aka not mixed in a song material

Comment: but do you have an example already mixed in a sound material? Just to hear how it sounds like? Best

Comment: Here is a guy playing the family guy theme song. Note the noises when he hits the strings. Every now and then he makes some noise http://youtu.be/Qld8i_h2vKs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to fret-noise? Arguably, the best, and more 'unique' results would be from recording your own, as @Ronald says. However, if that's not an option for you, as you've said you don't own a guitar, then:-

I'm not sure what your budget is, but Native Instruments Komplete comes with a load of different guitar Kontakt sample 'instruments', amongst other things, which have dials that control the amount of fret-noise you hear.

If you wanted a free option, then you could hunt around for free fret-noise effects such as [this one](http://freewavesamples.com/kawai-k5000w-fret-noise), throw them all into a sampler or create a patch for [Kontakt](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/samplers/kontakt-5-player/) (Player), then 'play' them underneath your guitar track.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to play in real acoustic enviroment and record it.
But if you just want to try it in vst/au plugins. You can use Guitar Rig, Real Guitar plugins.
For me, I used to do it in Hypersonic 2 + FL DAW.
Hypersonic 2 comes with many real guitar sounds including tapping sounds & hand sounds go across the strings.